# I can't install packages with conda, even so anaconda was correctly installed? (Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Setup)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, anaconda, conda, pandas

I wanted to install pandas on my fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (updated it first).

What i did:
I followed the installation instructions on:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/
(debian version, but with 'sudo apt' instead of 'apt-get')

The installation went through nicely. The sha256 were identical as well.
I followed every recommended step and even verified my installation (anaconda-navigator opens for example)

My issue now:
pandas can't be installed since it keeps throwing error like:

```
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

(it keeps finding incompatible packages, if you let the "installation" continue)

After that, i wanted to uninstall anaconda, but i can't even install anaconda-clean, which should be the uninstall package (same issues).

My question:

Did i miss something important, that i might have skipped?

In the best case scenario, i would like to install pandas via conda.
In the worst case scenario, i would like to uninstall anaconda with anaconda-clean.

The anaconda i used for the installation: Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh

Answer (score 0):

Another complete reinstall (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and using 'sudo apt-get' instead of 'sudo apt' for anaconda did the trick?

I still have no clue what might gone wrong the first time.
pandas gets installed alongside anaconda fyi.

Not sure if everything will work now, but at least `import pandas` doesn't throw an exception.